# java error incompatible types required int found double

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error in intellij idea.

> incompatible types. required int found double

I am new to java and don't know what this error is.

```
public class Temperature {
    public int calculateF(int cs){
        int f = cs * 9/5 + 32;
        return f;
    }
    public int calculateC(int f){
        int c = (f-32/1.8000);
        return(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The division by `1.8` results in a `double`. If you want an `int`, you need to cast or round. Something like,

```
public int calculateC(int f) {
    return Math.round(f - 32 / 1.8f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that the default primitive data type for decimal values in java is `double`. Based on the code `(f-32/1.8000);` you basically divide the value to  decimal which converts the result to be a `double`. Assigning it into `int` datatype will result into incompatible types which you encountered in your IDE. Workarounds will be either change your variable data type and return type or do not divide the `(f-32)`to a decimal value.